# Regex for multiple specific email addresses

Tags: regex

I am still figuring my way around regex and have come across a problem that I am trying to solve. How do I validate for multiple specific email addresses?

For example, I want to only allow testdomain.com, realdomain.com, gooddomain.com to be validated. All other email addresses are not allowed.

```
annie@testdomain.com   OK
aaron1@realdomain.com  OK
amber@gooddomain.com   OK

annie@otherdomain.com NOT OK
```

But I'm stil unclear on how to add multiple specific email addresses for the regex.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I am using Django for the backend and entering it in the registration form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean to include various ligitimate domains in one regex?

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(testdomain|gooddomain|realdomain)\.com\b
```

Comment: I replaced \b with ^ and \b for $ (I am using django) but it still does not match correctly: regex=r'^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(testdomain|gooddomain|realdomain)\.com$'

Comment: Just added [A-Za-z... from your answer and it worked :) Thank you!

Comment: here, `\b` represents a word boundary. It is fine for you te replace with your line start/end markers if that is what you are looking for. If you want it to match properly, you have to have the case insensitive flag set.

Comment: or use both `A-Z` and `a-z` in the matched character set

Comment: `Billy+Moon@gmail.com` is a valid email address and your solution will not match it...

Comment: @Ωmega - definitive regex for email does not exist. if you want to match all email addresses, without false positives, you will have to write something very long, and it won't be 100%. If you want to match all email addresses, not concerning yourself with false positives, you can just use `.+`. Most of us go for something in-between. I went with what was included in the answer (before seemingly being edited away), and was focussing on the part of the question that I think was the stumbling point.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which language you're using, but most regex implementations have a notion of logical operators, so the domain part of your pattern would have something like:

```
(domain1|domain2|domain3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(testdomain|realdomain|gooddomain)\.com\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above works for testdomain:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(?:testdomain|realdomain|gooddomain)\.com\b
```

Also, please note that you will have to add a case insensitive `i` modifier for this to work with your test cases, or use `[A-Za-z0-9._%-]` instead of `[A-Z0-9._%-]`

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/awKGjZYbOt)

Comment: u cant use regex to validate an email-address

Answer (score 0):

To make this expandable to many domains, I would probably capture the domain name and then compare that captured domain name with your whitelist in code.

.+@(.+)

First, ".+" will match any number (more than 0) of any characters up until the last "@" symobol in the string.
Second, "@" will match the "@" symbol.
Third, "(.+)" will match and capture (capture because of the parenthesis) any character string after the "@" symbol.

Then, depending on the language you are using, you can get the captured string.  Then you can see if that captured string is in your domain whitelist.  Note, you'll want to do a case insensitive comparison in this last step.

Answer (score 0):

The official standard is known as [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1).

Use *OR* operator `|` for all domain names you want to allow. Do not forget to escape `.` in the domain.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:testdomain\.com|realdomain\.com|gooddomain\.com)
```

Also use case-insensitivity modifier/flag to allow capital letters in the address.